# I felt sick just [ by / from ] watching that

Tags: grammar, prepositions

1. Which is the correct one?
2. And if there is not 'just', what would be the difference in using them?

Comment: Really, you don't need either one.  "I felt sick just watching that" is grammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of natural speech in British English, it's pretty much always ***from***, in my experience. No difference with or without the *just*.

Comment: Many people would say **after watching that** as an alternative.

Comment: @RonaldSole: Also **due to that**, **because of that**, and probably more - but the question was about two specific options.

Comment: I noted that too. My comment was intended to be helpful rather than critical.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask why 'by' sounds unnatural? I get the feeling, as a non-native, it sounds not that different from the 'by' as in "I was seen by them" or "I was full by eating all of it".

Comment: Well, the honest answer is "it just is". Not everything is logical. A linguist might have a better answer. I can hazard a guess, though, and your additional examples clued me in to it. You see, "I was full by eating all of it" isn't right, either. But "I was made full by eating all of it" is. And "I was sicked by watching that" is. It seems that one uses *by* with most verbs, and *from* with adjectives and linking verbs. *Felt* is a linking verb, and in *was full*, *was* is a linking verb, but *seen* isn't, and *sickened* isn't.